# Existing utility method to ensure that all collection elements are non null

Tags: java, java-8, guava

Is there an existing utility method in Java 8 standard library or in Guava which **ensures that the collection is not null and every element (if any) is not null?**

Like a "collection-version" of [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-).

I couldn't find anything like this so far. For now I wrote a trivial utility function which does the job:

```
public static void requireAllNonNull(final Collection<?> collection) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(collection, "Collection must not be null");
    if (collection.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull)) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Collection elements must not be null");
    }
}
```

But the problem is that it has to be duplicated in different (unrelated) projects.

One alternative would be to only use [*Guava's immutable collections*](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) which don't allow `null` values at all, but sometimes collections originate from other sources.

Comment: Your code is just fine and there is nothing built-in.

Comment: One option is to filter and ignore null values in iterations and streams from the collection. If you instead check up front, before using the values, and other code has access to the collection, then its contents might change between your check and later usage.

Comment: `if(collection.contains(null)) …`

Comment: I'd tend to write `collection.forEach(Objects::requireNonNull)`, which throws its own exception.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: that’s great for a `List` or any other collection allowing duplicates, but since the collection could also be a `Set`, a simple `contains(null)` would be faster, however, might fail if the collection doesn’t allow `null` in general (in which case the entire test is a waste). Given the additional fact that collections might be mutable, just doing the actual job and throwing when encountering `null` (which more than often happens implicit anyway), is the most pragmatic solution (or copying like in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for an `NPE` to be thrown, the easiest approach might be to just try to create a Guava [`ImmutableCollection`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.html), which requires all elements to be non-null (e.g. ImmutableList):

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(collection);
```

As far as *checking* for null elements, Guava has:

```
boolean allNonNull = Iterables.all(collection, Predicates.notNull());
checkArgument(allNonNull, "collection had null element");
```

But due to time-of-check/time-of-use vulnerabilities, you're usually best to copy to an immutable collection first anyhow.  If you check your invariants by iterating through a mutable collection, there's always the possibility that someone changes the collection *after* you validate it.

`ImmutableList#copyOf` also has the added performance consideration that if it's already an `ImmutableList` that is passed in, it just returns that list to eliminate any overhead.

Comment: I'd add that `ImmutableList` is from Guava.

Comment: Thanks @Tanuki, I've clarified that in the answer.

Comment: Assigning the parameter to a local variable and then using the local variable seems like a good solution to me. Like this: `final List<Type> theParam = ImmutableList.copyOf(param);` It is still readable, produces no `CheckReturnValue`-warnings. And it is `O(1)` in case `param` already was an `ImmutableList`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is something like `Objects.requireNonNull` you can simply do this:

```
myCollection.forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
```